# Prove for general form of function at -x containing derivatives of order n

Tags: derivatives, quantum-mechanics, symmetric-polynomials, legendre-polynomials, hermite-polynomials

I have stumbled across multiple casses of functions (explicitly Hermit and Legendre polynomials) for which I wanted to prove the symmetry. While doing so I always ended up with the following equations:

\begin{equation}
H_n(-x)=a *\frac{d^n}{dy^n}f(y)|_{y=-x}=a*(-1)^n*\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)
\end{equation}

Where $f(x)$ is an even function ($f(x) = f(-x)$)

Now my question: Is there a formal way to prove that I can in any case extract the factor of $(-1)^n$ from this derivative? Maybe using total differentials? And if so, how can I do it? For the specific cases I was able to prove it using induction but as far as solutions to these problems go, this was not necessary and the above step was just performed with no additional comments.

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: Isn't $f(-x)' =-f'(-x)$  (abuse of notation here) what you want ?

Comment: No, what you are saying is just describing the 0 function. If you meant to plug in x instead of -x in the first one, it's also just the definition of an odd function. But yes, in my case I want to show that the first derivative is odd, aswell as all other odd derivatives and all even derivatives give an even function

Comment: Are you trying to bypass the standard Rodriguez formulas?

Comment: No, I looking for differential rule that I can basically write over the second equal sign in the equation I stated. I only named the polynomials as examples but I want to know if and how I can make a general satement under the conditions named

Answer (score 1):

I fail to understand your question, really.
The formal definition of Hermites, however, cannot be what you wrote, but, instead, is
$$ H_n(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}~~~\leadsto \\
 \quad H_n(x) = \left(2x - \frac{d}{dx} \right)^n \cdot 1~~~.$$

It is then evident that the minus signs may be absorbed into *x*, s.t.
$$ H_n(-x) = e^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2} =
  (-1)^n \left(2x - \frac{d}{dx} \right)^n \cdot 1~~~.$$